# Problem to build an appbundle with VSCode and Flutter

Tags: gradle, flutter, build

After follow all the guide lines in https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest, i'm still getting error when i try to build my appbundle.

Any sugestions?

This is the VSCode terminal output:

Air-de-Juca:divulgae jucaesmanhoto$ flutter build appbundle
Initializing gradle...                                              3,1s
Resolving dependencies...                                          18,1s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Note: /Users/jucaesmanhoto/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Note: /Users/jucaesmanhoto/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Note: /Users/jucaesmanhoto/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.1.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/urllauncher/WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                      Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                       715,9s (!)
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Yes. It wasn't easy... I had ' flutter.buildMode=debug ' in my local.properties file. When i changed to ' flutter.buildMode=release ' it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, first i made a new project, and signed it before getting any changes in it.
Then i started to add the packages and build with every modification on my pubspec.yaml, AndroidManifest.xml or build.gradle files.
At the and, when i compared both projects, the problem was in my local.properties file.
where i should have flutter.buildMode=release, i had flutter.buildMode=debug.

Lesson learned: be careful when editing those files. :)